# Install python 3.5.1 on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, python

I would like to know how to install python 3.5.1 on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: There is this PPA: https://launchpad.net/~fkrull/+archive/ubuntu/deadsnakes

Comment: did you ever try this with a docker image?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to install Python 3.5 is with anaconda

https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install

Comment: this might be a small caveat, but what if your using a docker image that has ubuntu. Is anaconda still a good idea?

Comment: It's definitely possible to install Python 3.5 with Anaconda, but it's not obvious to me why it would be the easiest. Installing from PPA is similarly easy.